# undefined angularJS control function error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am discovering `angularJS`, but I get an error `Argument 'LawContrl' is not a function, got undefined`. In my `form`, I have in my rails app

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "LawContrl"}
  =form-for ... 
    %li{"ng-repeat"=>"entry in entries"}  {{entry.name}} //I am using haml file
```

in my laws.js.coffee file, I have

```
@LawContrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.entries = [
    { name: "hi"}
    {name: "ho"}
  ]
```

Comment: Can you try to make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Is the error in the JS console?

Comment: OK I had some similar problem. What does the console shows you ?

Comment: @Newben Oups, I have some `$ undefined` error

Comment: So is `jquery` correctly added ?

Comment: Yes I checked in my `application.js.coffee`, I have `//= require jquery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. I don't know what ide you're using, but rename (or refactor then rename if you're using `Eclipse` or `Rubymine`) your `application.js.coffee` to `application.js` and everything must be working just fine. Btw, you should declare some `LawContrl` module in your `angularJS` so the controller can be passed to the view

Comment: OK great I didn't know why this `application` file was renamed to a coffeescript one !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it could be, some things to check that might help with debugging this:

- angular.js library script is included only once in the page
- LawContrl script is included in the page after angular.js
- ng-app attribute (it can be empty) is present in the HTML
- If ng-app has a value, e.g. ng-app="foo", then LawContrl should be part of the foo module

Comment: A Fiddle reproducing the problem as @Blackhole suggests would be good. Otherwise perhaps try stripping the LawContrl down to its barest bones, don't pass $scope in and see if that helps you debug.